# How to add secondary index for HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.1.2 ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have inserted about 15 million rows and 32 columns in an hbase table through Map-Reduce.

```
# Key-valued data e.g.
company= ibm ! employee= sw ...

# In hbase it's look like
row =1 column = f1: company time stamp=1123344456 value =ibm ....
```

And while i fired  the query

```
(scan 'sample_names', {COLUMNS=>"f1:company", FILTER=>SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('f1'), Bytes.toBytes('company'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), SubstringComparator.new("ibm")) })
```

it took about **360.09** seconds to fetch the data.  **Is there a way to improve the performance of this query?** Can we reduce this query time by secondary indexing? If yes, please suggest how to add indexing for a particular column qualifier.

Comment: What is your hbase key? you can make your company name as part of your key and then filter based on the key itself.

Comment: hi Ravi Bhatt Thanx for your quick response :) . my hbase row key is "ROW ID " fetech from input file and stored in hbase table , each Unqique "ROWID" contains 32 column keys . And i  scanned for the column key value say "Company = ibm ".  but it took quite time to fetch the data , so what i believe is if we use secondary indexing for that company column then we may get good query performance . please suggest me if am wrong at way of functionality .

Comment: As far as i know, hbase does not support secondary indexes. You can a key which is a combination of column values such as id_companyName and you can filter records based on part of that key. You can use regular expressions too.

Comment: can u please suggest me in writing regular expression for the optimizing performance of the hbase query , ? what would be best query time for the 5 million records in hbase , like when i ran the single columnvalue filter query for the evendate = 01/5/2010 , it gave about ** 36 records out of 5 million records, and taken 154.09 seconds **, so please suggest me to improve the query performance  :) :)

Comment: Hey can u Please  look into this issue once ?->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344220/secondary-indexing-in-hbase-how-to-insert-the-data-in-secondary-column-table    [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344220/secondary-indexing-in-hbase-how-to-insert-the-data-in-secondary-column-table)